# How good is the Wubi?

Tags: installation, partitioning, wubi

Does the Wubi allow you to create a proper ext4 partition and install Ubuntu?
Or is it that the Wubi will only allow me to install it in the C partition?

Comment: Also note that Wubi will likely not be offered in the future because of too many issues.

Answer (score 0):

It runs under Windows file systems, not ext4. So it has to go on C.

Otherwise Ubuntu needs a separate partition formatted to ext4, in which case you won't need Wubi. You can install directly onto the partition.